# Perform DOM operation after it was updated inside onMutate in react-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I wrote a component called `Chat` (some parts are omitted for simplicity):

```js
function Chat() {
  const containerRef = React.useRef(null);
  const messages = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["messages"],
    queryFn: api.getMessages
  });
  
  const createMessage = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (message) => api.createMessage(message),
    onMutate: (message) => {
      // 1. cancels query, updates cache, returns previous value
      optimisitcUpdate(messages, message);

      // 2. scroll to bottom
      const { current: container } = containerRef;

      // ❌ won't work, because the DOM is not updated yet
      container?.scrollTo(0, container.scrollHeight);

      //  works, because the DOM is updated, but it's hacky
      setTimeout(() => container?.scrollTo(0, container.scrollHeight))
    },
  });

  return (
    <div id="messages" ref={containerRef}>
      {messages.data?.map((message) => (
        <div key={message.uuid}>{message.body}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

It's pretty straightforward. `useQuery` to fetch all messages, `useMutation` to create a new message, and return all of the messages.

Whenever `createMessage` occurs, I want to optimistically update the messages and then scroll to the bottom (like any other chat behavior).

The problem is, I have no way of doing `flushSync` inside `useMutation`, so as a workaround, I wrap the logic inside a `setTimeout`, but that's a hacky way.

I was wondering if there's a more robust approach than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to execute *after* the DOM rendering:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const { current: container } = containerRef;

  container?.scrollTo(0, container.scrollHeight);
)/*, [you may want to put some dependencies here to limit rendering]*/};
```

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid useEffect

Comment: This makes me curious ^^ You want to perform an operation after the rendering is updated, and that's exactly the purpose of useEffect : what is the downside of your use case ?

Comment: According to the official React docs, useEffect is meant to synchronize external APIs  (such as event listeners) with React itself. If I was outside of react-query, I was able to solve it using the built-in `flushSync` function. I could solve it with useEffect with a single dependency that would be `sentMessageAt`, but that would be hacky as well. I was hoping for a react-query specific solution that would allow me to "flushSync" or run after the DOM has been updated.

Comment: I'll accept your answer due to https://twitter.com/TkDodo/status/1587413174193733633